# To check for session variable on load of a page

Tags: javascript

On load of a page i need to check if a session variable exists or not from a Javascript. I tried the following code. But it gives an error saying session is undefined.

```
Json=// i have hardcoded value here
Session("hai") =  "";
Session.set("hai",json);


if (( typeof session.get("hai") == 'undefined' && ((session.get("hai") == null)||(session.get("hai") == "") ) ){

}
```

Comment: There's no `Session` or `session` by default in javascript. I don't really what you are trying to do, but it just can't work like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store something between page requests, you can use Local Storage, or Session Storage.

```
localStorage.hai = json; // persistent across multiple sessions
sessionStorage.hai = json; // persistent in current session
```

This has nothing to do with server side sessions, though. It is unclear what your requirements are, so not sure this is suitable solution for you.

Here is a link for more information about Session Storage: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/